# What is the better way to call a function before a form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to call a js function before a form is submitted. Is it better to bind the function to the form submit or to the on click of the button to submit the form? The respective code is below:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    fireTheFucntionBaby();
});
```

vs

```
$('#form-submit-button').click(function() {
    fireTheFucntionBaby();
});
```

...or is there an even better way of doing this?

Comment: I'd go with `.submit()`, simply because you can bypass `click` with the enter key.

Comment: Good point. .submit() fires "closer" to the form submission so that is a safe way to ensure it doesn't fail. Any yes, the enter key. Thanks!

Comment: If you had TinyMCE on that form, it would ask you "Do you really want to leave this page" in case you use `$('#form-submit-button')`. The form submit is kinda de-facto for such thing

Comment: Thanks djay - that's exactly the advice I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously any of these options work but another option would be ...

```
<button onClick('fireTheFucntionBaby();')> Button Text </button>

function fireTheFucntionBaby(){

     //your awesome code here

     submitFormFunction();
}
```

The performance will be extremely similar (insignificantly small difference) in all 3 cases. Because performance isn't an issue here I would decide based off of what you think is the cleanest, most maintainable way to write it.

if you think they are all equally maintainable, find a coin and flip that bad boy in the air. Heads is your first function, tails is your second function

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mike. I'm going with the `$('form').submit` solution for the reason discussed in the comments on the original question. I do think it's a bit cleaner externalizing it vs putting it into the HTML. Thanks for the response though - I was looking for answers around performance - which you touched on.